# Using thymeleaf and bootstrap to create a panel accordion from a list but collapsable function doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf, accordion, panel

I am very new to bootstrap. I am using bootstrap along with thymeleaf to create a collapsable panel accordion from a list. Iterating through the list works. Displaying the panel body works. At one point I was able to get the collapse function to work after iterating through the list, but that would only collapse the first panel regardless of which panel was actually clicked. What have below is a combination of the research I have done including what I have came across on stack overflow to get the collapsible function to work for all the panels, but not successful.

```
<!-- Accordian2-->
<div th:each=" title : ${titles}">
<div class="panel-group"  th:id="'accordion'+${title.id}">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class ="panel-heading" >
            <h4 class="panel-title" th:attr="data-target='#accordon'+${title.id}" data-toggle="collapse" th:text="${title.title}">
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Place holder</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```